# Converting a small external JS file to an inline script

Tags: javascript

I was using GTmetrix to check my site speed, and one of the recommendations was to take a tiny JavaScript file I was externally referencing and make it inline instead. I understand I need to add it inside script tags in the footer, but do I need to edit any of the existing content?

My code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
    jQuery('.hide-this-part-more').click(function () {
        // Get the hidden element
        var hidden_element = jQuery('#'+this.id).next();

        hidden_element.slideToggle('slow');
        // Change the more link text
        if (hidden_element.attr('status') === 'invisible') {
            hidden_element.attr('status', 'visible');
            // Make the morelink a lesslink
            jQuery ('#'+this.id).text('Less »');
        }
        else {
            hidden_element.attr('status', 'invisible');
            // Get the morelink text, that the user wants to be displayed
            var morelink_text = jQuery('#'+this.id).attr('morelink-text');
            // Make the lesslink a more link
            jQuery('#'+this.id).text(morelink_text+'  »');
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the external script is in some way involved with this click handler: No.

Comment: So I would just take the code above, wack it in a script tag, then remove this part from the plugin.php:  - // Load Hide This Part JS
add_action('init', 'hide_this_part_init');
function hide_this_part_init() {
 wp_register_script('hide-this-part-js', plugins_url() . '/hide-this-part/js.js');
 wp_enqueue_script('hide-this-part-js');
}

Comment: Uhm not sure @gadgetviper , but the only dependency seems to be that jquery is loaded, so it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.